# PHP warning: "Creating default object from empty value in . . ."

Tags: php, sql-server

I've tried the solutions that have been suggested here, but the warning persists.  This is the code that produces the problem:

```
$qryResults = array();
$qryResults[$sqlidx]->numrows = 0;  [This is the line pointed to by the warning message]
$qryResults[$sqlidx]->numcols = odbc_num_fields($resultSets[$sqlidx]);
```

There is also another reference to the $qryResults array which holds the results of the DB read:

```
$qryResults[$sqlidx]->fields[$qryResults[$sqlidx]->numrows][$j] = date('m/d/Y H:i:s',odbc_result($resultSets[$sqlidx], $j +      1));
```

The warning occurs on the first use of the array (numrows=0)
The PHP version is 7.4.3 running on Ubuntu 20.04

`$qryResults` holds multiple queries from MSSQL select commands.

The warning occurring doesn't preclude the code from working properly, but I'm at a loss on how to get rid of the warning.  (I don't like loose ends :-) )

I originally had it without the array assignment which caused the first observation of the warning.
I then tried defining the array as a 'stdClass' with the result of:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

These were the two options I was able to find with a Google search for this warning.

Comment: I can't figure out what your intention is. `$qryResults = array();` is an empty array.  Then you are trying to declare the `numrows` property of an object at `$qryResults[$sqlidx]`, but that object is never created.  I _guess_ you could do the intermediate step of declaring `$qryResults[$sqlidx] = (object) [];`, but I'm not sure this is just feeding an XY Problem. Do you instead want to do [your db processing] then have that property fallback to `0` if it was never populated?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that:

```
$qryResults = array();
$qryResults[$sqlidx]->numrows = 0;
```

You are trying to:

1. initialising the variable as an empty array
2. then trying to find a non-existent item and set properties like `numrows` to that non-existent item.

This is not production ready code, but to clarify what would work:

```
$qryResults = array();
$anItem = (object)array(
   'numrows' => 0,
   'numcols' => 'something_else',
);
$qryResults[$sqlidx] = $anItem;
```

OR

```
$anItem = new stdClass();
$anItem->numrows = 0;
$anItem->numcols = 'something_else';

$sqlIdx = 0;
$qryResults = array();
$qryResults[$sqlidx] = $anItem;
```